# One and the same code runs in a Console Application and throws a StackOverflow Exception in a WCF Service, using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, console-application

I have a WCF service and I try to retrieve a list of some entity objects.

I tried the following code in both - a Console Application and a WCF Service.

```
SomeEntities someEntities = new SomeEntities();
someEntities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

return someEntities.Publications.Include(p => p.User).ToList();
```

In the Console Application everything works fine but in the service, I get a StackOverflow Exception. Why is this happening?

Comment: Could you show the stacktrace?

Comment: The problem is quite probably that you're serializing an object with a circular reference.

Comment: As well as the stacktrace, show the model definition